# Mysql query to find highest and lowest among 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have got two tables say tableA and tableB. Both tables have fileds say pointA and pointB. I need a single query to find the highest and lowest value among the columns pointA and pointB.

```
 tableA
 idA    pointA
 1        20
 2        12
 3        41
 4        8     


 tableB
 idB    pointB
 1        24
 2        74
 3        2
 4        16
```

I want to get the result like this

```
 HIGHEST     LOWEST
    74         2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT MAX(point) as HIGHEST, MIN(point) as LOWEST
FROM
  (SELECT pointA as point FROM tableA
   UNION
   SELECT pointB as point FROM tableB) t
```

Comment: @Bibin Velayudhan: in my original query I forgot to give a name to derived table. Now it works as expected :)

Answer (score 1):

```
select max(pointB) AS result from tableB
union
select min(pointA) AS result from tableA
```

Comment: The highest value could be from `tableB` and the lowest from `tableA`. So your solution won't work. Pretty strange that you got this many upvotes for a wrong answer... :O

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MAX(high) AS highest
     , MIN(low)  AS lowest
FROM
  ( SELECT MAX(pointA) AS high
         , MIN(pointA) AS low
    FROM tableA
  UNION ALL
    SELECT MAX(pointB) 
         , MIN(pointB) 
    FROM tableB
  ) AS tmp
```

Comment: Any thoughts on the performance and scalability of this solution vs the accepted answer?

Comment: @Philip: A good optimizer would perform equally well. I would surely test both versions before selecting one or the other. If I were to blindly choose, I'd use this one, as it will surely use the indexes of `pointA` and `pointB` (if any), before doing the last operations on the derived table - which should be really fast as it will have only 2 rows.

Comment: @ypercube thanks - of course testing is crucial. I would guess that `UNION`s are hardly fun at the best of time.

Comment: @Philip: This could be done with a `CROSS JOIN` as well. Perhaps that's more of your taste :)